# Inscribed circle in Archimedes's spiral

Tags: geometry

The spiral begin with a 1 centimeter radius and end with a 5 centimeter radius. How inscribe 750 000 000 circles in the spiral? They not cut themselves. I searched to draw the circle on the average curve (with an half turn late) but the curve distant is not constant. It's a specific rate expension: the circles need to be the biggest possible. The circles lie between and touch successive rotations of the spiral.

Comment: Do we have the freedom of selecting the expansion rate of the spiral?

Comment: Should the circles lie between and touch successive rotations of the spiral?

Comment: The circle's center are on the average curve (sorry I am better in french to explain) but the circles just touch the main curve. Yes the circles lie between and touch successive rotations of the spiral.

Comment: You are going to need roughly $10000\sqrt{5/\pi}$ loops in the spiral to fit that many circles.

Comment: Yes maybe (I am not good in math) but I need too to know at least the angle position of the centers to have an angle equation of the center.